# multiple condition using CONCAT in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

iam using concat function but i cant use multiple condition in this function, only one condition allow while iam checking my result, please help me and give corect resolution and my code is bellow...

```
$this->db->select("pay_status,pay_invoiceid,GROUP_CONCAT(
                     CONCAT (jil_payment.pay_id,'-',jil_payment.pay_amount,IF ( 
                       jil_payment.pay_status='4','(submited)' 
                       AND jil_payment.pay_status='2','(deposited)'))) as paymentdetail");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `FALSE` arg like this :

```
$this->db->select("pay_status,pay_invoiceid,GROUP_CONCAT(
                   CONCAT (jil_payment.pay_id,'-',jil_payment.pay_amount,IF ( 
                   jil_payment.pay_status='4','(submited)' 
                   AND jil_payment.pay_status='2','(deposited)'))) as paymentdetail", FALSE);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer....but the issue is not solved, same issue continuely